# Android apps calling web service design logic

Tags: java, android, web-services, web, webserver

I has an android apps install in my galaxy tab.  This apps will call a web service in the web server which locate in the office.  The web service then will call to database in another server.  The web server and database server is in same LAN.  My web server IP is dynamic which will change every time the modem is restarted and I do not register any domain name.  How I can configure my router/modem to let the apps can call the web services which the ip is not statics?  Is it possible?  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What is OS of your webserver running ? Windows or Linux? You should configure a static IP for your webserver machine. This way webserver IP 'll not change after modem is restarted. You may find this in [Google search](https://www.google.com.pk/search?biw=1366&bih=634&q=configure%20static%20ip%20windows%207&spell=1&sa=X&ei=gAxjVeyMNYrXyQPQtYGgBw&ved=0CBcQvwUoAA#q=configure%20static%20ip)

Comment: My web server is running Windows Xp/7 .  You means set the static internal IP for the web server like 192.168.1.xxx or I get my current public IP and set it in my web server or router?

Comment: Follow the instructions from here http://www.colorado.edu/oit/tutorial/static-ip-configuration-windows-7. P.S: This will work within your local network/router. It wouldn't be accessible from outside network.

Comment: Hi Junto, if need access outside the network like access from other country/location which not connect to LAN in the office?  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you need to have static ip from your Internet service provider but this 'll cost you extra. Then setup port forwarding on your router http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router   This way with your static ip and a port you 'll be able to open it from outside of your network.